# PrintDocument is printing filename string instead of document in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I am implementing `PrintDocument` in my asp.net project wherein i need to print specific pages of my document but instead of document being printed, its the string of "fileName" which is getting printed. Below is my code

```
 string fileName = "C:\\DocToPrint\\Sample2018.pdf";

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      using (PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument())
        {
            pd.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
            pd.PrinterSettings.ToPage = 1;
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages;
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
            pd.Print();
        }

 public void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(fileName, new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Black,
                             ev.MarginBounds.Left, 0, new StringFormat());
    }
    }
```

What is being missed here? Please suggest..Thanks

Comment: Well, as the name suggests, the method `DrawString` draws a string. And the string that you supply is the file name.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth How to print file instead? What method needs to be used?

Comment: @Lara, you need to open another question for your new query.

Comment: @Lara You want print specific page of in `fileName ` path?

Comment: @Hossein Yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

There's a nuget package called Spire.Pdf that's very simple to use. The free version has a limit of 10 pages although, however, in my case it was the best solution once I don't want to depend on Adobe Reader and I don't want to install any other components.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.PDF/

```
PdfDocument pdfdocument = new PdfDocument();
pdfdocument.LoadFromFile(pdfPathAndFileName);
pdfdocument.PrinterName = "My Printer";
pdfdocument.PrintDocument.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;
pdfdocument.PrintFromPage = index;
pdfdocument.PrintToPage = index;
pdfdocument.PrintDocument.Print();
pdfdocument.Dispose();
```

Sample for printing some page.

https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/print-one-page-from-pdf-t6586.html

Comment: Thanks but i do not want to use any third party dll..Is there a way to print directly from C# instead?

Comment: @Lara if exist I don't know.